# Evaluate affinity rules

Tags: kubernetes

I updated a statefulset deployment and the deleted pods of that statefulset are pending forever. Thus I described the pods and saw that they can not be scheduled on nodes because the nodes didn't match the pod affinity/anti-affinity rules. This statefulset however has no affinity rules at all.

**My question**

How can I evaluate the affinity rules of my statefulset, so that I can see what affinity rules are hindering these pods from starting?

I believe it must be a different deployment which hinders these pods from starting up, but I am clueless which deployment it might be.

Comment: After they failed, did you ran `kubectl describe` on them?

Comment: Yes that's why I know that they can not be scheduled because they do not match the pod affinity/anti affinity rules. I'll update the thread with the original output from describing the pod.

Answer (score 0):

check this in order to determine the possible root cause

- check if your nodes have taints (`kubectl describe node {Node_Name} | grep Taint`), if it is the case look for tolerations in order to schedule a workload in a specific node.
- you have in the definition the field `nodeName` and is being pointed to an no existing node.
- as Prateek Jain recommended above check your pod with describe in order to see what exactly is being overriden in your definition.

Comment: Hi, the node is not tainted nor is the nodeselector the reason. My info already comes from describing the pod. It says there is no node because x nodes didn't much node selector, 2x nodes do not have sufficient resources and 3 nodes did not match affinity/antiaffinity rules.

Answer (score 0):

Statefulsets pods might be preventing the deletion because you may have some pv-protection, the best way to troubleshoot that situation is running `kubectl get events -n ${yournamespace}`, any event on your namespace will be listed.

Try to see if any warning or error message is displayed.

NOTE: If you get too many events, try to filter using `--field-selector=type!=Normal,reason!=Unhealthy`

✌

Comment: Maybe that was worded unclearly, but I don't have issues deleting the pod. I meant they are pending (because they cannot be scheduled) AFTER I deleted the pod successfully.

Comment: oh, I see, still the command valid for your case, any event generated by the scheduler will be shown, there are several reasons not to get your pods pending of scheduling (resource starvation, affinity, adminission control flags and so on ...)